# ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for OktaAuthStateService

Tags: angular, okta, angular-providers, angular17

Attempting to implement a guard with Okta authentication in Angular v17, I encountered an error indicating a lack of provider for the OktaAuthStateService.
Upon logging in through Okta, I gain access to the login status component. However, when attempting to navigate to the dashboard using routes, I encounter an error related to the absence of a provider, specifically the OktaAuthStateService.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Router, UrlTree, } from '@angular/router';
import {  Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OktaAuthStateService } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { Observable, map, take } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class AuthGuard { constructor( public authStateService: OktaAuthStateService, private router: Router ) {}

canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> { 
return this.authStateService.authState$.pipe( map((loggedIn) => { console.log('loggedIn', loggedIn);
if (!loggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }),
  take(1)
);
} }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OktaAuthModule, OKTA_CONFIG } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import myAppConfig from './app.config';
const oktaConfig = myAppConfig.oidc;
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);

@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [OktaAuthModule],
providers: [{ provide: OKTA_CONFIG, useValue: { oktaAuth } }],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes, mapToCanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { OktaCallbackComponent, OktaAuthGuard } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { LoginComponent } from './modules/auth/components/login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './core/guards/auth.guard';
import { DashboardComponent } from './modules/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginStatusComponent } from './modules/auth/components/login-status/login-status.component';
import { CommonGuard } from './core/guards/common.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
redirectTo: 'login',
pathMatch: 'full',
},
{
path: 'login',
component: LoginComponent,
},
{ path: 'login-status', component: LoginStatusComponent },
{ path: 'implicit/callback', component: OktaCallbackComponent },
{
path: 'dashboard',
canActivate: mapToCanActivate([AuthGuard]),
component: DashboardComponent,
},
];
```

Comment: angular is enforcing functional guards, insteaod of class ones. if you transform your guard to the functional one the problem should go away, because it will be created on the other injectior

Comment: it return this error: ERROR Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for OktaAuth: (?).

Comment: are you injecting `OktaAuth` instead of `OktaAuthService` somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved with the following configuration update:

app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      OktaAuthModule.forRoot({ oktaAuth }),
    ),
  ],
};
```

Comment: did you happen run into this same null injector issue in unit tests? how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `OktaAuthStateService` in your route:

```
path: 'dashboard',
providers:[OktaAuthStateService]
```

Comment: It's not functioning as expected when I include it in the app.config; instead, it generates a different error: ERROR Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for OktaAuth: (?). `export const oidc = {
  clientId: environment.clientId,
  issuer: environment.issuer,
  redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
  scopes: environment.scopes,
};

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oidc);
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    { provide: OKTA_CONFIG, useValue: { oktaAuth } },
    OktaAuthStateService,
  ],
};`